# Bigquery - Substitute field if other field is blank

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've got this code here:

```
select DealID,ExternalReference,order_number, sales_rule
from flostream.orders
join mobileheads.surveys on flostream.orders.ExternalReference = mobileheads.surveys.order_number
//where DealID is null
```

What I want to happen is IF DealID (in flostream.orders) is null, replace it with sales_rule (in mobileheads.surveys)

Please let me know if this can be done with Bigquery or if you can think of some workaround?

Thanks!

Nik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
IFNULL(expr, null_default)  
If expr is not null, returns expr, otherwise returns null_default.
```

You should read more about them in the [manual](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference).

Your query would look like:

```
SELECT IFNULL(DealID,sales_rule) as DealID,
       ExternalReference,
       order_number,
       sales_rule
FROM flostream.orders
JOIN mobileheads.surveys ON flostream.orders.ExternalReference = mobileheads.surveys.order_number
```

Comment: Hi I have one question. Could I do this on a join? this new result (combo of all dealIDs) I need to look this up in another table and pull data from there, would I be able to do this?


SELECT filename,ifnull(dealID,mobileheads.surveys.sales_rule)
FROM [flostream.orders] 
left outer JOIN flostream.briisk ON (ifnull(dealID,mobileheads.surveys.sales_rule)) = Uniquereference
left outer join mobileheads.surveys on mobileheads.surveys.order_number = ExternalReference

Comment: It's unclear, but certainly it's possible. You need to use a subquery to obtain this "table" and then join based on the alias.

Comment: Could you show me how to construct a subquery with a random example for this as I kept getting an error when trying subqueries in bigquery?

Comment: Try something like this: select * from
( SELECT filename,
       ifnull(dealID,mobileheads.surveys.sales_rule) as dealID
FROM [flostream.orders]
 ) as derived
LEFT OUTER JOIN flostream.briisk ON derived.dealID = Uniquereference
LEFT OUTER JOIN mobileheads.surveys ON mobileheads.surveys.order_number = ExternalReference

Comment: It doesn't like the mobileheads.surveys.salesrule in the subquery, it says: Error: Field 'mobileheads.surveys.sales_rule' not found.

(Field definitely exists!)

Comment: you will need to post another question for that, I will be off a bit (will delete this comment).